# Problem with updating record in database

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-model, validation

I have problem to update user data in cakephp.

When I submit form I have this data in $this->data:

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => Dusan
            [last_name] => Stojanovic
            [native_language_id] => 25
        )
)
```

but, when i try to update it with:

```
$this->User->id = $id;
$this->User->save($this->data)
```

model is not saved, because of validation. They try to validate field which don't exist in $this->data array (like invalid password, email etc.). How I can fix this so I can update only fields that exist in $this->data array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To [properly do this](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1145/One-Rule-Per-Field) you should set the validation rules' `on` option to `create` only and/or set `require` to `false`.

For a quickfix, supply a [`$fieldlist`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data) of fields you want to save:

```
$this->User->save($this->data, true, array('first_name', 'last_name', 'native_language_id'));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need. Actually, I need to remove required from validation and set to allowEmpty.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
$this->data['User']['id'] = $id
```

because of the ['id'] cakephp recognizes the array as data that will update a dataset and will not create a new data set.